# Why does UDP socket takes such long time in Python?

Tags: python, performance, sockets, websocket, udp

while i'm testing sockets in python ,i'm wondering why does it takes such long time  to complete a UDP send & receive process.
(it takes about 2ms per contact **LOCALLY** with my code ,it's just too slow to use it communicating between processes or threads)

Am I doing some thing wrong ?(run in single thread or something?) Or it's because python is just that slow ?

Server demo code like this :

```
import socket,time

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind('localhost',6000)

while True:
    data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
    s.sendto(b'',addr)
```

And client is like this:

```
import socket,time

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)\

for i in range(100):
    t = time.time()
    s.sendto('localhost',6000)
    s.recv(1024)
    print(time.time() - t)
```

the output is like this:

```
0.00799250602722168
0.0020029544830322266
0.0010268688201904297
0.0010089874267578125
0.0010042190551757812
0.0020051002502441406
0.002005338668823242
0.002005338668823242
0.002005338668823242
0.002005338668823242
0.002005338668823242
0.002005338668823242
0.0020051002502441406
0.0020058155059814453
0.0027120113372802734
0.0010039806365966797
0.0020055770874023438
0.00200653076171875
0.002003908157348633
0.0010035037994384766
0.0020051002502441406
0.0020074844360351562
0.0010325908660888672
0.002005338668823242
0.002690553665161133
0.0010037422180175781
0.0020055770874023438
0.0020051002502441406
0.002005338668823242
0.002005338668823242
0.001806020736694336
0.0010192394256591797
0.0010271072387695312
0.0020055770874023438
0.002007007598876953
0.0020041465759277344
0.002004861831665039
0.001999378204345703
0.0020067691802978516
0.0019817352294921875
0.002007007598876953
```

Can anybody solve my problem?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get about two orders of magnitude faster than that (~0.01ms, 3.4GHz i7-6700) maybe `localhost` resolves somewhere strange and it needs to retry things?

your code also doesn't work for me, am posting the code I used.  server side first:

```
import socket

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as s:
  s.bind(('localhost',6000))
  while True:
    data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
    s.sendto(b'',addr)
```

now client side:

```
import socket
from time import time

addr = socket.getaddrinfo(
  'localhost', 6000,
  socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)[0]

with socket.socket(*addr[:3]) as s:
  s.connect(addr[4])
  for i in range(1000):
    t1 = time()
    s.send(b'')
    t2 = time()
    s.recv(1024)
    t3 = time()
    if i % 100 == 0:
      print('{:.3f}ms {:.3f}ms'.format((t2 - t1) * 1000, (t3 - t2) * 1000))
```

note that I use `socket.connect()` to try and cut down on resolution time, but this doesn't seem to make any difference for me.  I get:

```
0.218ms 0.006ms
0.004ms 0.010ms
0.004ms 0.007ms
0.004ms 0.008ms
0.004ms 0.011ms
0.004ms 0.010ms
0.004ms 0.010ms
0.004ms 0.009ms
0.004ms 0.010ms
0.004ms 0.008ms
```

back, i.e. first time around is slow, then it's quick

unix domain sockets might be faster if you care less about portability, otherwise you could try [zeromq](http://zeromq.org/) which has [nice Python packages](https://pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Thanks ! Perfectly solves my question ! After added socket.connect() transfers become rocketly fast (with each communication takes about 40μs on my computer) ,could you please explain why it gets way faster just after added this one single line  magic code?

Comment: Does it make any difference on reliability or something ?

Comment: at a guess you were performing DNS lookups on every `send()`, this could perform a network round-trip and would take 1–2ms on a relatively fast network.  doing the `connect()` once will cause resolution to happen once and then work with IP addresses from then onwards.  you could test by putting `getaddrinfo()` into a loop and seeing how long it takes.

Comment: as far as reliability is concerned; it can affect things if you expect the IP address associated with a host name to change.  obviously this won't affect `localhost` (which should always point to `127.0.0.1`) but might affect other hostname, hence why python takes its time doing the DNS lookups for you

Comment: It turns out that changing 'localhost' into '127.0.0.1' makes difference,thanks!